# Android deep link and issues non clickable links or not working links

Tags: android, deep-linking

I made an Android application in which I want to implement deep linking (example: http://myApp/seeMore?id=123456)

When I send a sms via intent, I receive it, and the link is clickable, and it opens the content of the application I want to see!

What's the problem? If I send myself the link via whatsapp (or messenger), I receive it, but this same link in the whatsapp message is not clickable!

I also tried the format myApp://seeMore?id=123456 (with the Manifest xml updated as it should be), but nothing happens, the link sent is not clickable, even via SMS.

The only time I had a clickable link in whatsapp and messenger, it's with the http://myApp.com/seeMore?id=123456 format. But when I click on the link, it opens the browser saying that the page does not exist.

And I saw that in this case, I have to link my app to my website but I don't have a website... And I don't want to have one!

Questions :

Is there a way to make "myApp://seeMore?id=123456" clickable in SMS, Whatsapp, Messenger apps? By forcing in the code to say that it's a hyperlink? something else? :) )

Is it possible to make the link "http://myapp.com/seeMore?id=123456" work to point directly to my apk and not to the browser? (Did I configure my intent-filter wrong?) I saw a style attribute verifyAuto=true in the xml manifest, but when I tried, it didn't work...

Is it possible to generate a clickable link (even if it's not a url?) via intent send to messenger/whatsapp?

Does anyone have any idea whatsoever for my concern? :)

Here it is, if you have any idea, I'm interested! Thanks for reading and possibly helping me :)

Translated with [www.DeepL.com/Translator](http://www.DeepL.com/Translator) (free version)

**My current AndroidManifest:**

```
<activity
    android:exported="true"
    android:name=".vue.activity.GraphActivity"
    android:screenOrientation="landscape"
    android:launchMode="singleTask"
    android:parentActivityName=".vue.activity.MainActivity">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
        <!-- Accepts URIs that begin with "http://speedchyps/course” -->
        <data android:scheme="http"
            android:host="speedchyps"
            android:pathPrefix="/course" />
        <!-- note that the leading "/" is required for pathPrefix-->
    </intent-filter>
    <meta-data
        android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
        android:value=".vue.activity.MainActivity" />
</activity>
```

**Config when i try "maJolieAppli://seeMore?id=123456":**

```
<intent-filter android:label="@string/filter_view_example_gizmos">
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
    <!-- Accepts URIs that begin with "speedchyps://course” -->
    <data android:scheme="speedchyps"
          android:host="course" />
</intent-filter>
```

Comment: Please post your AppCompatActivity class or how you are handling      Uri uri = getIntent().getData();

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.